# Can "pounding" be used here?

Tags: word-choice

Michael grabbed the man by the collar with one hand and started pounding him with the other.

Can I use "pounding" here as I have instead of "punching"? Or what would be the more natural choice of word to tell that he starts hitting him hard with his fist repeatedly?

Comment: _Pounding_ is fine here, but I don't find it very natural. I wouldn't be surprised to find it in a novel, but I would be surprised if somebody said it if they were telling me what they had just seen.

Comment: You usually ***pound*** with ***fists***, not *[other] **hands***. That's the only reason the example is *slightly* "off". But it's [not an unknown usage](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22and+was+pounding+him+with+the+other%22), as those written instances in Google Books show. There's also [***pummeling***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22and+was+pummeling+him+with+the+other%22) if you don't like ***pounding***.